# Eliminating empty key value pairs from dynamic column

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have an update policy which populates a target table column of dynamic type. The update policy logic for populating the dynamic column is as:-

```
project target_calculated_column = pack("key1",src_col1,
                                        "key2",src_col2,
                                        "key3",src_col3,
                                          .
                                          .
                                        "keyN",src_colN)
```

The columns src_col1,src_col2,...,src_colN are fixed number of columns coming from a specific table which is source for the update policy. These columns are of various datatypes, mostly some of them are strings and others are integers. Also the main thing here is that these columns may or may not contain any values for the input rows. What this means is that for integer columns values could be null or in case of string columns it could be blank. Now the issue here is that the update policy function is obviously written before hand and hence it can't know which rows will have nulls or blanks etc. That's something that will only be known when update policy starts running. So when the update policy starts running we end up with the following type of data in the target column target_calculated_column , showing one sample value from target row:-

```
{
  "key1":"sometext",
  "key2":30,
  "key3":null,
  "key5":"hello",
  "key6":"",
  "key7":112,
  "key8":"",
  "key9":"",
  .
  .
  "keyN":10
}
```

This demonstrates the problem. I don't want to keep the key value pairs as part of target_calculated_column which are empty (nulls, blanks etc.). I think what I am asking for is a conditional version of `pack()` that can ignore key value pairs with empty values, but I don't think such an option is there. Is there way I can postprocess target_calculated_column so that I can eliminate such key value pairs?  Basically in case of this example I should be getting the following output:-

```
   {
      "key1":"sometext",
      "key2":30,
      "key5":"hello",
      "key7":112,
      .
      .
      "keyN":10
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pack_all([*ignore_null_empty*])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packallfunction) function allows you to ignore nulls/empty values. If you want to remove some columns you can use the [bag_remove_keys()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-remove-keys-function) function. The [pack()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packfunction) function itself does not provide this option.

Comment: In that case , is there any scalar operator that will allow me to partition a row into multiple groups of columns and then create a calculated column for each group ( in this case calculated column will be formed using pack_all(true) for a given group) and then finally merge all the columns together ?

Comment: the best i can think of is to split the table using a let statement and do a join. If you do not have a key you can use the new_guid() function

Comment: yes but that will be a tabular operation instead of a scalar one -- so it will have performance tradeoff , looks like that is the only way out though. I will see if it makes sense to sacrifice performance to achieve this.

Comment: BTW, having multiple columns that all do pack_all() and removing the applicable keys from each of them will probably be the fastest and the easiest. i.e. | extend Group1= bag_remove_keys(pack_all(true), keys_to_remove), Group2=bag_remove_keys(pack_all(true), keys_to_remove)